# Cookies not preserved in ASHX handler

Tags: asp.net, cookies, httphandler, ashx, ihttphandler

This is a single page application which uses a cookie to hold a guid of the users server login. Server httpgets are all wrapped into a single ASHX file and are all invoked by jQuery $.ajax(). The only web file in the project is a htm file which hosts all the javascript to make it happen.

When I set a cookie using Response.Cookies I get a different value when I inspect it to Request.Cookies, and when I set a Response.Cookie, the corresponding Request.Cookie on the next server visit still contains some old value, not the value just set.

I have added these two lines to the handler ASHX file:

```
Implements System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
Implements System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState
```

I have also changed the IsReusable property to true:

```
ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return True     
    End Get
End Property
```

Neither of the above changes helped.

When I inspect Session.SessionID, its different on every server call, which I suspect is the root of the problem - should it not be the same ?

The webserver is the Visual Studio 2015 debugging web server, not IIS.

Cookies are got using request.Cookies("name").Value and the set function is as follows:

```
Public Sub SetCookie(ByVal Response As System.Web.HttpResponse, ByVal sCookie As String, ByVal sValue As String, Optional ByVal lTimePeriodMinutes As Integer = 30 * 24 * 60)

    sCookie = sCookie.ToLower

    Response.Cookies.Remove(sCookie)

    Dim obj As New System.Web.HttpCookie(sCookie, sValue)
    obj.Expires = DateAdd(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateInterval.Minute, lTimePeriodMinutes, Now)
    Response.Cookies.Add(obj)

End Sub
```

The above has worked for many years on an old version of the app.

The problem is the same on IE and Firefox

Comment: You should implement one interface not both in your HttpHandlerHandler. try IRequiresSessionState

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had tried that but before I got to try it again the problem went away. I think what happened is that there was a kind of a "hanging" cookie that refused to go away, as soon as I deleted cookies, it started working (in IE and FF). I'm still working on it and will post updates asap

Comment: Yes, confirming that deleting cookies fixed it for good. Its something about changing the "implements" of the class seemed to make cookies become ghosted, such than an old cookie value was appearing.. strange !